# How to update changes from Master branch to current branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab

This question may be duplicated ,but I did not find answer from other questions.

I have 3 branches:

```
 BranchA 
 
 master branch

 BranchB
```

First I clone code from master to BranchA,and wrote code in BranchA.

But during I was coding in BranchA ,master branch code changed ,since other coders was coding at BranchB and then merged BranchB to master branch.

How can I update BranchA from the merged master branch before I merge it to master branch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this while working on a remote branch? Let's assume so.

If remote master received new changes, you can merge these changes in your clone of master as follows. First, checkout your own master:

```
git checkout master
```

Then fetch the remote changes

```
git fetch upstream
```

and apply them to your local master,

```
git rebase upstream/master
```

If that didn't give you any issues, simply go to your branchA

```
git checkout branchA
```

and apply the changes in this branch

```
git rebase master
```

Now, branchA should be up to date with the remote master including changes made by third person in branch branchB.